# Adding background to h1, only on apty space

Tags: css, html-heading

I'm trying to achieve this kind of effect

[image: Basic example]

Basically, I want the background for my heading to span across the available space, but not under the text. The problem is that this needs to be dynamic as the text can be in multiple languages. I can't simply put another background in a separate span for the text, since the overall background used a pattern image, and it can't just randomly start and stop depending on the length of the text.

I hope i made myself clear enough!

EDIT: since the example was not clear enough, here is another one:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support the maximum number of browsers, then you need to add some additional markup for this to work:

http://tinker.io/b6848

```
<h1><span>Header Text</span><span/></h1>

body {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/600/400);
}

h1 {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 span {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: pre;
}

h1 span:last-child {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
}
```

There is a way to do this without additional markup using Flexbox, but it currently only works in Chrome, Opera, IE10, Firefox builds with experimental Flexbox support turned on, and maybe Safari.

Comment: amazing, this is exactly what i meant. i knew it had something to do with table cells! :D thank you SO much!

Answer (score 2):

Put the `<h1>` in a wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Then style the background as `table-cell` with 100% width.

```css
div.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

div.wrapper h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #056;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 1em;
}

.background {
    background-color: #000;
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laucheukhim/K6mfW/3/embedded/result/).

Comment: No, as i said i can't do it because the overall background has a pattern image :/

Answer (score 0):

just put h1 into div

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

and then stylize it http://jsfiddle.net/yh6Nn/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure CSS hack, you may want to explore `:after` pseudo-element and `content` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/FYDXr/2/

I have no idea how to make it fill remaining space, though.